# which things get loaded with class object into RAM whenever we instantiate that class by new keyword?

Tags: java

for every class, what things get loaded into memory with that class when we instantiate it with new keyword? as we know, every class is subclass of Object class, at the time of instantiating any class by new keyword , Object class data also gets loaded into ram. I read that, all classes of java.lang and java.util also gets loaded, whenever we instatiate any class by new keyword. I want to know that other than Object class data, all classes of java.lang and java.util which things gets loaded into memory?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's not quite clear what you're asking. Does [this question about memory management while loading classes in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475218/how-is-memory-managed-while-loading-classes-in-java) or [this other question about what is stored in memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284482/is-the-java-class-file-stored-in-jvm-memory) help any? Can you add some clarification to what you're asking?

Comment: It depends entirely on the inheritance hierarchy of your object, the variables defined in it, their inheritance hierarchies, if they are initialized or not at object creation, if the object is static, and many other things... This question is exceedingly hard to answer.

Comment: Thanks mark and shoover. Yes I try to clarify my question.

Answer (score 1):

The runtime memory is divided into the `Heap` and the `Stack`. The Heap stores all the objects that are instantiated during runtime and the Stack stores all the methods that are invoked during runtime. The created Object contains all the `instance variables` inside itself and all the Class's methods and goes to the Heap.
However, all the `local variables`, the variables that were created inside an invoked method all go to the Stack.